# my django view is always throwing "unexpected keyword argument error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

i am familiar with python and started to learn django and it is fun in the begining how ever a table insertion becomes nightmare to me from 2 days and always throwing the following error

```
sample() got an unexpected keyword argument 'firstname'
```

i have tried all the possible ways on documentation and stackoverflow but nothing works.
but another view with same syntax got worked for me that's so weird.
here are my files.
this is my stack trace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\manee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\manee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\manee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\manee\myapp\PE\views.py", line 77, in sample
    a=sample(firstname=name)

Exception Type: TypeError at /sample
Exception Value: sample() got an unexpected keyword argument 'firstname'
```

this is the combination of the worked view and troubling view(problems is working fine,sample is not working).

```
def problems(request):

    name=request.POST['name']
    title=request.POST['title']
    difficulty=request.POST['example']
    description=request.POST['description']
    solution=request.POST['solution']
    code=request.POST['code']

    question=problem(name=name,title=title,difficulty=difficulty,description=description,solution=solution,code=code)
    question.save()
    return render(request,'thanks.html')


def sample(request):
    name=request.POST['name']
    email=request.POST['email']
    rno=request.POST['rno']
    a=sample(firstname=name,email=email,rno=rno)
    a.save()
    return render(request,'example.html',{'name':name})
```

and here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

#Create your models here.
class problem(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    difficulty=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description=models.TextField()
    solution=models.TextField()
    code=models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class sample(models.Model):
    firstname=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email=models.EmailField()
    rno=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname
```

please get it fixed fast

Comment: Your `sample` model doesn't have `name`. You're trying to store it in `name`, which doesn't exist - maybe you want to store it in `firstname`? Try changing `a = sample(name = name, ...)` to `a = sample(firstname = name, ...)` OR in your `sample` model, change `firstname` to `name`.

Comment: Short code to reproduce the error: `def sample(request): sample(name='')`. Now call `sample` with any value and you'll get the `TypeError` because you try to call the function again, but this time with a non-existing keyword.

Comment: i tried it but didn't work

Comment: Read (and understand) the answer from Willem Van Onsem.

Comment: You’re not calling the model sample, just this local sample function, which only has request.  Uppercase Models classname to Sample, fix your imports, call Sample(firstname...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `sample` model has no `name` field, only a `firstname`, but that is *not* the problem here. The problem is that your views have the *same* name, so if you call `sample(..)` it will call the *view function*.

Normally models start with an **U**ppercase, although not required, it makes it easier to make a distinction between the names of the *models* and the *views*. You thus can define the models as:

```
from django.db import models

#Create your models here.
class Problem(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    difficulty = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description = models.TextField()
    solution = models.TextField()
    code = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Sample(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField()
    rno = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname
```

In the views, you can then use the model with:

```
from .models import Problem, Sample

def problems(request):
    name=request.POST['name']
    title=request.POST['title']
    difficulty=request.POST['example']
    description=request.POST['description']
    solution=request.POST['solution']
    code=request.POST['code']
    question = Problem.objects.create(
        name=name,
        title=title,
        difficulty=difficulty,
        description=description,
        solution=solution,
        code=code
    )
    return render(request,'thanks.html')


def sample(request):
    name=request.POST['name']
    email=request.POST['email']
    rno=request.POST['rno']
    a = Sample.objects.create(firstname=name,email=email,rno=rno)
    return render(request,'example.html',{'name':name})
```

That being said, it is normally better to use a [**`ModelForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/) (or at least a `Form` to process input), this makes it less error-prone, and more convenient to process data.

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
>   [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
>   to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
>   This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
>   browser.

Comment: i have replaced first name with name but no use

Comment: @maneeshsandra: as said before that will *not* fix the problem. You are calling the view function, not the constructor of the model.

Comment: so what i have to do now?

Comment: @maneeshsandra: read the *entire* answer and try to understand why making two things with the same name is asking for trouble.

Comment: i have done everything you have said but not working same error with different names

Comment: @maneeshsandra: then edit the question with the new error. You did use `Sample` instead of `sample` (in both the model and the view)?

Comment: What you are saying is my model and view must not be same right? One should be in caps(model) and view must be in small am i right

Comment: @maneeshsandra: that is what [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) advises. It does not *have* to be, but if it has the same name, you need to use all sorts of tricks to make clear what you are calling, and then it goes wrong, like in your case.

Comment: Ok now i understand what you have said thanks for your time.  I will do this in the morning and if things didn't work i will again post another question after clearing all my faults